# How to find all methods in the .NET framework that accept or return a specific type?

Tags: .net, arrays, frameworks, types, find

This is probably a stupid question, but I still have no answer.

I would like to know if there is a method or technique that returns all the methods in the .NET framework which accept or return a specific type.

**Example:**

- I would like to find all methods in the .NET framework that return arrays;
- I would like to find all methods in the .NET framework that accept arrays as a parameter.

**Note:** I tried the Object Explorer in Visual Studio, but it seems that's not the kind of thing I want. It takes loads of time to search through all the classes and their methods, inspecting each parameter.

Comment: Is there a reason you need that?

Comment: probably just to boost productivity. just for the sake of explanation i have a codeSnippet that that returns arrays and i have another piece of code that accepts another type instead of relying on custom untested code why not seek for a ready made tested solution in the framework itself

Comment: I agree that it would be nice having such a tool -- you could e.g. analyse your own source code to find coupling between different components, visualise them as a dependency graph, etc. But some points deserve some more thinking; e.g.: 1. How would you be dealing with polymorphism and type variance? (If you search for methods returning a Fruit, should a method that returns an Apple be included in the search result or not?) 2. Concerning arrays specifically, would you make a difference between a `SomeType[]` and `SomeOtherType[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx). With the reflection you can enumerate all the classes and their methods in a single [assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx) (using [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx), [GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) and then [GetMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td205ybf.aspx)), and get the [parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx) [types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.parametertype.aspx) and [return type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.returntype.aspx).

You can find a simplified example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.aspx) (it doesn't deal with [generic methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isgenericmethoddefinition.aspx), this is a separate story; [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ReflectGenerics.aspx) should be helpful).

Comment: +1, since that's the only possibility that does not rely on some third-party tool or IDE. Of course the OP will have to decide on which assemblies to include in the search.

Comment: @Deeptechtons, do you realise what you're asking for? This wouldn't just be a teeny-wheeny code snippet, but a fair amount of work. Instead of just asking for working code, why not try to write it yourself? If you end up having problems with this task, that'll be the right time to learn about .NET reflection (there's much learning material on the 'net), or ask more specific questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sure k stakx i agree. Thought would be easy just realized it wasn't when i googled.